# Layer Comps in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, layer-composition

I am using the layer comps in photoshop to create different pages of an app display setup. When I change the position of the text for layout "d"  it then makes layouts a,b,c  all the previous comps change. It also happened to an image I re-sized and re-positioned, Would anyone be able to explain why this may happen?

To confirm:
All 3 of the layer options are checked on
I am refreshing the file upon updating

Comment: Layer comps do not understand resizing. So each comp always has the same size layers. As for the position, are you sure your layer comps have the option `position` selected? If it's not, then the position will be same for every layer comp (that doesn't have it). --- The only other way I see this happening is if you are selecting all layer comps before pressing the update layer comp button.

Comment: Resizing I realized it does not capture but there are two separate issues the resizing and the moving  of the other elements. I have triple checked my check boxes...I believe it may be the nesting of the folders there are many folders nested within each other and it seems that my be effecting it.

Answer (score 1):

I also use photoshop in the process of making complex single page apps with multiple revealed divs. The solution I've worked out is to make multiple copies of the same layer.

I might have a folder structure that goes:

```
Annotations
Header1
Header2
   Left   (I'm not concerned about semantic HTML issues in photoshop layer comps.)
   Middle
   Right
Body
  Left
  Middle
  Right
```

Inside these sections I would have duplicate copies that's associated with the state/sub-program. These duplicates would be revealed or not revealed; modified or not modified as the case may be.